# Boxplot with percentage based on nonnumeric number in R

Tags: r

I have a df

```
A     B
WT    R+P
Mut   S+P
WT    S+P
```

I would like to generate a box plot where x = A and y = % B.

So for the first bar where A=WT the Percentage = 33% (1/3) for B and
for A=Mut the Percentage = 33% (1/3)
my code so far is

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=counts(B)) +
geom_bar() +
lab("Percentage") +
facet_grid(~A)
```

but of course I get the error message non-numeric argument to binary operator.  Help please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included some code here that I think is getting at what you are trying to do here. My feeling is that the graph you are creating at the end is a little weird. It doesn't add up to 100 for one of the facets that you created. You also had a small error in your ggplot (ylab vs lab)

```
A <- c("WT", "Mut", "WT")
B <- c("R+P", "S+P", "S+P")

df <- data.frame(A, B)
df


df <- df %>%
  mutate(B_numeric = case_when(
    B == "R+P" ~ 1,
    B == "S+P" ~ 1))

df

df_grouped <- df %>%
  group_by(B) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(B_numeric))

df_grouped <- df_grouped %>%
  mutate(pct = total / sum(total))

df_grouped

df <- left_join(df, df_grouped, by = "B")
df <- df %>% select(A, B, pct)
df

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=pct)) +
geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
ylab("Percentage") +
facet_grid(~A)
```

[image]